# JSON is becoming empty upon hitting server code

Tags: javascript, node.js, networking, fetch

I am sending a fetch request with a JSON payload from my webpage like this:

```
let raw = JSON.stringify({"name":"James","favourite":"books"})

var requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: raw
};

let send = () => {
    fetch("http://mywebsite.herokuapp.com/send", requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(result => console.log(result))
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
}
```

On the server side I am getting an empty body {}. Here is the code I use to monitor that:

```
app.post('/send', (req, res) => {  
    console.log(req.body)
})
```

When I send the exact same code generated with Postman to server — somehow everything works fine, and I get the correct JSON. Please help me understand why that is.

Comment: Try setting Content-type header in your options

Comment: Are you sure that your `fetch` function accepts options as second parameters?

Comment: @charlietfl you are the mvp, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the server, `req.body` will be empty until you have [middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.json) that matches the content type in the POST and can then read the body from the response  stream and populate `req.body` with the results.

```
// middleware to read and parse JSON bodies
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/send', (req, res) => {  
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send("ok");
});
```

And, then on the client side, you have to set the matching content-type, so the server-side middleware can match the content-type and read and parse it:

```
const requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: raw,
    headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
};
```